# Soft question: Does Spivak encourage students to look up identities?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

For a few days i was stuck with the problem of proving $\sum_{k=0}^l\dbinom{n}{k}\dbinom{m}{l-k}=\dbinom{n+m}{l}$

I tried to look up the problem on google, but the answers were extremely complex and were both lengthy and used a great many symbols which i didn't even recognize (I am a freshman).
After being stuck with it for a while i asked on this board about the summation of two sigmas, and finally got the answer in the form of the Cauchy product. However i'd never even heard of the Cauchy product and neither did my mathematics teacher.

Does this imply that Spivak expected his students to look up identities and solutions? Because so far the tone of the book implies that everything is based off of something else that is used in the book already (Although i'm only at the second chapter)

Comment: There is a very illuminating combinatorial proof of this identity. Think of two sacks: one with $m$ different tokens and one with $n$ different tokens. Calculate in two ways how you many ways you can choose $l$ tokens from the total number of tokens $m+n$...

Comment: I assume the Cauchy produce solution is to consider the degree $l$ terms in (1+x)^m·(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{m+n}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem actually seems fairly straightforward to me (although I have no idea where Spivak got it). The argument is this:

To pick $l$ items from a set of $n+k$ items, we can pick some (say $k$) from the first $n$, and others from the remaining $m$ items. The number $k$ that we pick from the first $n$ can be anything from $0$ to $\ell$, hence the summation.

The number of ways to pick $k$ items from the first $n$ is the first factor in the summand; the number of ways to pick the remaining $\ell-k$ items from the remaining $m$ items is the second factor in the summand. Since these choices are independent (once you've chosen $k$), the number of possible choices is the product of these two.

In short, the proof's just a a counting argument.

What's certainly true is that Spivak did not intend students to look this up on the internet, because when the book was written, there was no internet. :)